# Node JS redirection after mysql request

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, node.js

I am trying to do a register page with node JS and MySQL, all is working except that I can't redirect the user on an other page. It doesn't take into account the "action" in my form, i can't use window.location in my server.js and when I try :

```
response.writeHead(301,
  {Location: 'index.html'}
);
```

I got the moved permanently error.

So, this is my form :

```
<form method="post" action="index.html" id="registerForm">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" /><br/>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" /><br/>


            <label for="password_bis">Confirmation</label>
            <input type="password" name="password_bis" placeholder="Password" id="password_bis" /></span><br/>

            <label for="language">Language</label>
            <select name="language" id="language">
               <option value="fr">Français</option>
               <option value="en">English</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

This is my js to retrieve the content :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#registerForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("http://localhost:1337", { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val(), language: $("#language").val() } );
    });
});
```

And this is my server :

```
var http = require('http');
var queryString = require('querystring');

var server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    var requestBody = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
      requestBody += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
      var postData = queryString.parse(requestBody);
      if(postData.username && postData.password && postData.language)
      {
        var post  = {username: postData.username, password: postData.password, language: postData.language};
        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
            res.end();
          } 
        });
      }
    });
  }
}).listen(1337);

var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database: 'test'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('CONNECTION error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You're submitting the form via AJAX, but then you want the page to redirect? You need to use a regular request. Don't send it via javascript, that makes it needlessly complex. Additionally, you may want to look into the `Express.js` web framework. It makes handling POST requests much easier.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is preventing it from redirecting/submitting, what's wrong with `window.location` ?

Comment: @Greg Unfortunaly it's a project where I can't use any framework or libraries.

Comment: have you tried with `302` header?

Comment: @Spokey I can't use window.location inside the server.js node.js doesn't know what is window.location.

Comment: You use it on the client side, after the post is successfull you redirect

Comment: @Spokey Yes I could but in the login case I have to check if the username and login are good before redirecting and this happens inside the server part :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of code:

```
$("#registerForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://localhost:1337", { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val(), language: $("#language").val() } );
});
```

Should be removed.

It is causing your request to be sent to the server via AJAX, and from there you cannot redirect the page. If you remove the code, it should work as expected.

If you have to use javascript (to pre-process the form or something), you can send a location to redirect to via `response.send`, and then in the post handler, use window.location.

Your client side code should look like this:

```
$("#registerForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://localhost:1337", { 
        username: $("#username").val(), 
        password: $("#password").val(), 
        language: $("#language").val() } ).success(function(data){
            window.location = data;
        });
    });
});
```

And your corresponding server side code would look like this:

```
res.end('index.html');
```

Comment: It work using this : res.end(JSON.stringify({location:'index.html'})); but I'm redirection to : "undefined" instead of "index.html"

Comment: @user3198601 `$.parseJSON(data).location;`

Comment: @user3198601 well it was only almost, I was thinking about `.send()` from websockets :D that puts it in an extra `data`

Comment: @user3198601 that was another Express-ism, I've edited the code to work without using JSON.